# Dynamically add element using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a survey project using Angular. One implementation not sure is how to dynamically render the child element based on user's input. For example a multiple-choice question can have multiple child questions with their child questions after the parent question is selected. I used directive to display different types of questions according to their question types(text, multiple choices, single choice, etc.), but how to add and display their child questions with Angular?

Thanks a lot.

```
HTML:
<h3>Recursive Questions</h3>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="recursiveQuestionTemplate">
    <span>{{question.QuestionDescription}}</span>&nbsp;
    <span>{{question.QuestionType}}</span>&nbsp;
    <div ng-include="'/TestTemplate/'+question.QuestionType+'.html'"></div>
    <br />
</script>
<div class="answer" ng-controller="TreeController">
    <form>
        <div ng-repeat="question in recursiveQuestion" ng-include="'recursiveQuestionTemplate'">

        </div>

    </form>

    <my-custom>Test1</my-custom>
    <div class="my-custom">Test2</div>
</div>



SingleOption HTML template:
<div ng-repeat="answer in question.Answers">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="{{answer.AnswerID}}" name="{{answer.ParentAnswerID}}"
               childquestionid="{{answer.ChildQuestionID}}" ng-click="renderChildQuestion(answer.ChildQuestionID,$event)" />
        {{answer.AnswerDescription}}
        {{answer.ChildQuestionID}}
    </label>

</div>



JS snippet:

    app.controller("TreeController", function ($scope, $http) {
        //Tree controller used to control template render
        $scope.renderChildQuestion = function (childQuestionID, $event) {
            parentAnswerId = $event.currentTarget.id;

            $scope.parentAnswerId = parentAnswerId;
            $http.get("/Home/GetQuestionById/" + "test").then(onQuerySubQuestionComplete, onError);
            // return child element info
        }

        //$scope.ChildQuestionID = 111;

        var onQuerySubQuestionComplete = function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            //test with Jquery to add element
            $("#" + parentAnswerId).parents().eq(2).append('<input class="C' + parentAnswerId + '" type="textarea" ng-model="response">new element append here</input>');


            var ele = angular.element("<span />");
            switch ($scope.user.QuestionType)
            {
                case 'text':
                    ele.append('<input type="textarea" ng-model="response">test append</input>');
            }
            //use return type to render html template
            //$compile(ele);



        }
        var onError = function (reason) {
            alert(reason.data);
            $scope.error = "Could not get the data.";

        }

    //...
    app.directive('myCustom', function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'EC',
                    templateUrl:
                        function (elem, attr) {
                            return '/TestTemplate/SingleOption.html';
                            //return '/TestTemplate/' +  question.QuestionType + '.html'
                        }
                };
            });
```

Comment: Please provide some code. We do not magically know how your angular app is structured ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `$scope` variable  equal to an array. The array will be an array of questions. When you retrieve the next question, it gets pushed to the `$scope.yourArray` variable. In the view you have:

```
<div ng-repeat="q in yourArray"></div>
```

Now when you retrieve the new question and add it to the array, it will update the view list of questions.

Your specific case may be more complicated, but this should help.